# jquery - day month year validation

Tags: jquery

I'm having separate select boxes for day, month, year validation.
12 ... 
JanFeb ... 
20092010 ...

If I use jquery validation plug-in, it displays separate error messages for each fields if it not selected.

But I want to treat all the three as a single field, and display error message.
if day is selected and month and year are not selected. then the error message would be please select a month.
if day and month are selected then it should be please select the year etc.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try using the datepicker function of jQuery-UI? You can have an alternate field that show the date in the format you want (so you can parse it in case you want more validation) and another field so you can show a user friendly format.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/